PolyPhase Merge Part
Help to write a method of merging files for Multiphase sorting. There is a GetDistributedSeries method, which distributes series to files according to the principles of multiphase sorting and returns an array with the number of dummy series for each file (index - file number, value - number of dummy series). We need to implement a method that will merge files into an empty one until one of them is subtracted completely, then the merge will go to the file that was subtracted. And so on until we have an ordered array in one of the files. Now about empty series. If we have fictitious series on all files, then in fact, we do nothing, but simply reduce the value of fictitious series in the array, and add 1 to the index of the file in the array to which we merge. If we merge dummy series with regular series, it means that we essentially skip one series merge for a file with an empty series and don't forget to reduce the value in the array.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class PolyPhase
    {
        private int helpAmount = 4;

        public int ReadHelpFiles { get { return helpAmount; } }

        public string[] CreateHelpFile(string helpDirectoryPath)
        {
            string[] filePaths = new string[ReadHelpFiles];

            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ReadHelpFiles; i++)
                {
                    string fileName = $"helpFile{i + 1}.txt";
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(helpDirectoryPath, fileName);
                    using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(filePath)) { }

                    filePaths[i] = filePath;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
            }

            return filePaths;
        }

        private List<int> GetPerfectSequence(List<int> a)
        {
            List<int> newA = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                newA.Add(a[i + 1] + a[0]);
            }
            newA.Add(0);

            return newA;
        }

        private List<int> SeriesCounter(List<int> a)
        {
            List<int> d = new List<int>();
            for (int k = 0; k < a.Count - 1; k++)
            {
                d.Add(a[k + 1] - a[k] + a[0]);
            }
            d.Add(0);

            return d;
        }

        public List<int> GetDistributedSeries(string mainPath, string[] helpFilePaths)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(mainPath) || helpFilePaths.Any(path => !File.Exists(path)))
            {
                
                return null;
            }

            List<int> a = new List<int>();
            List<int> d = new List<int>();

            int readHelpFiles = helpFilePaths.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < readHelpFiles - 1; i++)
            {
                a.Add(1);
                d.Add(1);
            }
            a.Add(0);
            d.Add(0);

            List<int> fictionalSeries = new List<int>();
            int currentIndex = 0;
            List<int> input = new List<int>();

            try
            {
                var fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(mainPath);
                foreach (var line in fileContent)
                {
                    if (int.TryParse(line, out int number))
                    {
                        input.Add(number);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
                return null;
            }

            try
            {
                File.Delete(mainPath);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
                return null;
            }

            try
            {
                while (d.Any(x => x > 0) && currentIndex < input.Count)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < d.Count; i++)
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(helpFilePaths[i], true))
                        {
                            while (d[i] > 0 && currentIndex < input.Count)
                            {
                                int seriesStartIndex = currentIndex;

                                while (currentIndex < input.Count - 1 && input[currentIndex] <=        input[currentIndex + 1])
                                {
                                    currentIndex++;
                                }

                                for (int j = seriesStartIndex; j <= currentIndex; j++)
                                {
                                    sw.WriteLine(input[j]);
                                }

                                currentIndex++;
                                d[i]--;

                                for (int k = 0; k < d.Count; k++)
                                {
                                    fictionalSeries.Add(d[k]);
                                }
                            }

                            if (d[i] == 0 && i == d.Count - 1)
                            {
                                d = SeriesCounter(a);
                                a = GetPerfectSequence(a);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int countToRemove = fictionalSeries.Count - 4;
            if (countToRemove > 0)
            {
                fictionalSeries.RemoveRange(0, countToRemove);
            }

            return fictionalSeries;
        }
        
    }
}


